# Google Analytics - Track Payment errors / Customer not returning after payment

Tags: google-analytics, usage-statistics

I recently started tracking our bookings on the website. But now I need some more customized reports.

Our Setup:

- We have a `WordPress` site, where we have our products displayed
- We have a booking engine(subdomain) which I track with the same ID
- We have a `Payment Gateway`, not trackable by `Google Analytics`

In my latest report I see that only 3% of all people starting the booking process, actually return from the `Payment Gateway`. I assume that there are a few you will loose once you have to enter the credit card, but 97% drop sounds too high for me. Maybe there is a problem with the `Payment Gateway`?

I already set up some Goals to help me keep track of the people, and get the numbers above:

- Goal 1 : Destination booking_start
- Goal 2 : Destination booking_confirmation

I would like to create a custom report, which shows me the countries of all customers leaving for the payment, and not returning.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on http://superuser.com/tour

Comment: Also, it's unclear what you're asking. What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?